# Resize image to its initial size

Tags: swift, image, animation, size, scale

I am using 2 animations.
when the screen is launched, the first animation starts in `viewDidLoad`.

this animation is applied to 2 images called `layer2` and `layer3`.

```
func firstAnimation(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options:
            UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat , animations: {

                self.layer2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
                self.layer3.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
        }, completion: { finished in

        })
    }
```

when an image called `layer0` is long pressed, then `firstAnimation`() is being stopped by this code:

```
layer2.layer.removeAllAnimations()
layer3.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

and different animation is being applied to `layer2` and `layer3`.

the second animation is

```
func secondAnimation() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 20, delay: 0, options:
            UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut , animations: {

                self.layer2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
                self.layer3.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)

        }, completion: { finished in

        })
    }
```

when I want to delete the second animation and launch the first one again, the 2 images layer2 and layer3 are starting from the size that they gained because of the second animation. how to relaunch the first animation with the initial sizes of the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset views that were transformed to their original scale by using `CGAffineTransform.identity`.

For example:

```
layer2.transform = .identity
```

Comment: A perfect solution. Thank u.